# GetTypeInfo Performance in Windows Store Apps

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, windows-store-apps, portable-class-library

When porting from the .Net Framework 4.5 to a Portable Class Library profile or Windows Store apps, a big change for Reflection-heavy libraries and applications is transitioning over to the [Evolved Type System](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/08/28/evolving-the-reflection-api.aspx), i.e. moving from `Type` to `TypeInfo`.

It might be tempting to do it the easy way and transform a lot of code from this:

```
someType.AccessReflectionAPI();
```

...to something like this:

```
someType.GetTypeInfo().AccessReflectionAPI();
```

This makes a lot of `GetTypeInfo` calls, which leaves me worrying. Since in the .Net Framework 4.5 `TypeInfo` derives from `Type`, the `GetTypeInfo` implementation is trivial (and might even be JIT-inlined?), but what about the implementation for Windows Store Apps and .Net Core?

**How big of an impact is calling GetTypeInfo** on those platforms? Will each call create a new object? Will each call mean a dictionary lookup? What's the overhead here?

Answer (score 0):

GetTypeInfo being a static reflection method will not create new objects, so the only overhead is speed. You're correct in that most of reflections guts are JIT inlined, and C++/CLI based code - performance really isn't a problem from my experience.

If you're interested the reflection api's internals are pretty simple to reason about if you look through mscorlib in reflector or another assembly inspector.

Comment: Not sure what being a static reflection method has to do with creating or not creating new objects - depends on how they're implemented, doesn't it? Which is kind of what I'm asking. I already looked through mscorlib, but it was of course the .Net 4.5 one. Not the one I'm interested in - where did you find the Windows Store App implementation?